# can I say "我们这个学期学过的课比上个学期多十课”？

Tags: comparison

I try to translate the sentence  "this semester we have studied 10 lessons more than previous one".我们这个学期学过的课比上个学期多十课”？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct.
"我们这学期比上学期多学10课。" may be a better translation.

Comment: thank you for a better translation! Is my translation grammatically correct?

Comment: IMHO, your sentence is Ok. I just have one revision. Generally a noun needs a classifier (量词) in Chinese language. Here, if you refer 课 to a subject (e.g Math， English, Music etc.), the correct classifier is 门. If it refers to a class of some subject, you should use 节 or 堂。 I would say 我们这个学期学过的课比上个学期多十门 or 我们这学期比上个学期多上十门课.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind in Chinese typically a measure word is between number and noun. So "十门课” maybe a better expression even your sentence is understood. In Taiwan people could have said “十科” rather than “十门课”. Also most foreigners tend to speak in very formal words, expressions and grammar when they start to learn Mandarin. If I were in this situation, I would say something like "这学期我比上学期多十门课。”

Comment: Another counter will be 堂. Both are used by native speakers.

Comment: Dead on.So you are not only handsome and super cool but knowledgeable in Mandarin.

Comment: Although I have to point out "十堂课” refers to 10 in-classroom sessions rather than 10 separate courses. If a student says, " 我这个礼拜有十堂课.” It refers to 10 sessions within the week while some course takes multiple times per week.